# Editing multiple entries in Jabref

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to edit multiple Jabref entries? E.g. add the same data to an empty field, like "keywords", of multiple files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Select the entries you want to edit, then choose "Tools">"Set/clear fields" in the menu bar. This will bring up a dialog prompting what field and what value (also with a "clear" option). There's also a checkbox allowing you to set only the empty field to a certain value.

Comment: This functon can be found under "Search" in JabRef 2.8 and above.

Comment: On JabRef 4.3.1 it can be found at: "Edit > Set/clear/append/rename fields..."

Comment: On JabRef 5.0 it can be found under "Library > Manage Field Names and content"... and wow, those JabRef developers need to lay off the moving around of options...

Comment: On JabRef 5.11 it can be done via "Edit > Automatic field editor"